# Optimization in oracle with java

Tags: java, oracle11g

my question is this, I have more than 1 million records in one txt and another in a csv separated by ";" the idea is to register the data to oracle using java without delay, because for the moment I am creating a stored procedure, inside that procedure I make an insert with their respective parameters and from java I read the data of txt or csv and I call this procedure, but I'm delaying 1000 records per minute, the idea is to delay uploading said data, Please, if someone has an idea of how to make this case, I would be grateful. Regards!(attaching screenshots)

> Proc Almacenado
>   [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pnhad.png)
>
> Codigo Java
>   [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uxH6h.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bn7h5.png)

> Excel
>   [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/migeM.png)

Comment: What you want is not clear, can you explain it better, and also provide your code so we can see what is going on.

Comment: investigate `sqlldr` or external tables, likely faster than anything you could write yourself.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow!

It's not clear what's the problem here.

To make a reply more likely, 1) structure your question in paragraphs, 2) be a bit more concise in what you want to do ('Oracle' is not specific enough, the company has a lot of products), 3) Provide commented example code that you already have, 4) If you have multiple questions, create a single question on SO for each.

Hope that helps you! :)

Comment: Add your code as text, not as images.  See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question and http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know that it is a little late to answer this question I asked about 2 years ago. But the solution was using SQL Loader, I had to arm my ctl file and run it with sqlldr but from java, since in my case I had to run it from a jar

Answer (score -1):

As far as I understand your question your processing of data is too slow. You have a few options:

- Split the txt and let different threads do the work for you. Combine them later on.
- split the incoming data in smaller tables
- Upgrade your hardware and get a SSD for example